# ngResource $save is wiping out models

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

I create a new model with `new MyModel({description: 'default'})`

Later, I save it.

```
$scope.myModel.$save(function(updated){
   do stuff here?
});
```

My problem is that the `$save` method is wiping out all fields. Why would that happen?

```
$scope.myModel.$save(function(updated){
   updated.description - undefined
   $scope.myModel.description - undefined
});
```

The ONLY thing I've found that works right now is this:

```
var copy = angular.copy($scope.myModel);
$scope.myModel.$save(function(updated){
   copy.description - not undefined
});
```

This seems to contradict the docs. What's going on?

Comment: Check your server side, I think you don't have description field in your server side model. So what happend? $scope.myModel is passed to server and updated by response object, response object does not contain description field

Comment: Post that as an answer and I'll accept it. $save and update both use the server response to update the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your server side, I think you don't have description field in your server side model. So what happend? `$scope.myModel` is passed to server and updated by response object, response object does not contain description field